# How to set email properties for custom domains in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a program that allows users to send emails. To do that my code asks the user to enter their email (the sender email). Then the program checks to see what comes after the '@'. If its gmail then I set the properties as such:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

If its yahoo, then I set the properties as such:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port","465");                                        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.host","smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port","465");
```

Then I create a session object using the properties as such:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator()    {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
});
```

The above works fine. What I want to do is let the program know what the settings should be in case the user has a domain that is hosted on google or microsoft. So for example instead of the email being yyy@gmail.com, it would be yyy@customer-domain.com. Is there a way for my program to know where the email is hosted or will I have to let the program ask the user? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any way around asking the user.

Comment: Why do you want to authenticate on the user's mail server ?

Comment: I want the user to be able to send an email from their own account. The above is the only way I know of.

Comment: This would be very complex. Every email hosting service can choose its own port and authentication method. Many users are not technical enough to provide that for you, and there is no global list containing this data for every possible email hosting service - and some users even have their own private SMTP servers.

Comment: Thats why I don't want to allow for the possibility of any hosting service. Just the top 3 or 4 perhaps. In the OS mail client or outlook on Windows you just enter the email and the program knows the rest of the configurations. Is there anyway to implement this in small scale programs?

Comment: It may interest you to see [how Outlook does it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507(v=office.14).aspx) and see if using the same method works for you.

Comment: Thunderbird has an [autoconfiguration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) mechanism as well.